# Android Studio Relay plugin (version 0.3.07) error

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-plugin, figma

I was following this tutorial "https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/relay/convert-designs-android-studio" to try out the Relay plugin for the first time. I have no problem following the previous steps of the tutorial, however when I get to import design from Figma to Android Studio, I encounter an error, which I have captured from the `idea.log` file:

```
2023-06-26 11:35:13,463 [1300963]   INFO - #c.g.r.a.p.i.FigmaService - fetching UI Package from Figma
2023-06-26 11:35:13,466 [1300966]   WARN - #c.g.r.a.p.i.FigmaService - Unable to set permissions on /home/ducanh/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/relay_android_studio/bin/linux_x86_64/figma_to_adin: /home/ducanh/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/relay_android_studio/bin/linux_x86_64/figma_to_adin
2023-06-26 11:35:13,467 [1300967]   INFO - #c.g.r.a.p.u.ShellCommand - Running shell command: /home/ducanh/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/relay_android_studio/bin/linux_x86_64/figma_to_adin
2023-06-26 11:35:13,511 [1301011] SEVERE - #c.g.r.a.p.i.FigmaImportWorker - There was a problem importing the Figma file
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/ducanh/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/relay_android_studio/bin/linux_x86_64/figma_to_adin" (in directory "/home/ducanh/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/relay_android_studio/bin/linux_x86_64"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:594)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.utilities.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.kt:33)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.utilities.ShellCommand.runUnchecked(ShellCommand.kt:77)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaService.importFile(FigmaService.kt:263)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaService.importPackagesToTemp(FigmaService.kt:127)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaImportWorker.doInBackground(FigmaImportWorker.java:76)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaImportWorker.doInBackground(FigmaImportWorker.java:31)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 14 more
2023-06-26 11:35:13,513 [1301013] SEVERE - #c.g.r.a.p.i.FigmaImportWorker - Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
2023-06-26 11:35:13,513 [1301013] SEVERE - #c.g.r.a.p.i.FigmaImportWorker - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-06-26 11:35:13,513 [1301013] SEVERE - #c.g.r.a.p.i.FigmaImportWorker - OS: Linux
2023-06-26 11:35:13,514 [1301014] SEVERE - #c.g.r.a.p.i.FigmaImportWorker - Plugin to blame: Relay for Android Studio version: 0.3.07
```

Seemed like it was missing the `figma_to_adin` file in the `/home/ducanh/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/relay_android_studio/bin/linux_x86_64` directory. I was also searching for this error but no result found. I wonder if any one has encountered this error and abled to fix it. If you need any additional information, just comment, this is the first time I ask a question so it might not be too clear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you found a solution to this yet? I'm running into the same problem after installing the Relay plugin in Android Studio (0.3.07) with a "No such file error". Looks like the `figma_to_adin` file is being incorrectly added under `relay_android_studio/bin/macos_x86_64` instead of `linux/x86_64`.

Edit: an updated version (0.3.07-hotfix) has just been pushed which fixes this issue :)

Comment: Thank you, after updating the Relay plugin the problem has been fixed and I can import UI packages from Figma normally.